# I get IndexError when compiling python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, indexing

I am writing a cryptosystem program in python that involves to shift left the key
I get `"IndexError: string index out of range"` when I compile the code.

Below is the function of left shifting

```py
def shift_left(key):
    s = "" 
    for i in range(1,len(key)): 
        print(i)
        s = s + key[i] 
        s = s + key[0] 
        key = s 
        s = ""  
    return key
```

I added the command `print(i)` to know for which value of i the index is out of range
It always print `1` and `2`

So the problem occurs when `i = 2`
I have no idea why it's out of range

Comment: You are overwriting key in your loop. Your range limits are fixed and s is always two characters long. If key is longer than 2 characters it will fail.

Comment: On the first iteration, when you assign `key = s`, `k` will now be what used to be `key[i] +  key[0]` - for example, if you call it with `key='test'`, it will set `s` to empty, then add `'e'` (`k[i]` for `i` is `1`) and then add `'t'` (`k[0]`), and then it sets key to `s`, i.e. `'te'`. On the second loop, with `i` now being `2`, `key[2]` doesn't exist and you get your error.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
def shift_left(key):
    s = "" 
    for i in key:
        print(i)
        s = s + i
        s = s + key[0] 
        key = s 
        s = ""  
    return key
```

Comment: @Hiten004m What makes you think this is a new question? It looks like an answer to me.